# How does changing the domain of a function change it’s bijectivity?

Tags: functions

I have this function

$f(x)=\frac{x+5}{x-8}$

Why is it different when I’m working from $\mathbb R\setminus8$ to $\mathbb R$ and from $\mathbb R\setminus8$  to $\mathbb R\setminus1$  when trying to prove bijectivity?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that $(x+5)/(x-8)=1$ would lead to a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

$F(x)=(x+5)/(x-8)$ is not surjective onto $\mathbb R$,

because $1\in\mathbb R$ and
$(x+5)/(x-8)=1$ leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Surjectivity is the property that every element of the destination set of the function has at least one preimage by the function. Obviously, it depends on the destination set.